# Java Label Integer

Tags: java, label, int

I want to create a Java counter that counts the amount of wins a person has in a game. I tried the following:

```
int winCount=0;
winCounter=new Label(int winCount);
```

Eclipse tells me to convert winCount into a string, but I need it to work mathematically. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do `""+winCount` to convert an integer to a `String`.

Comment: Also, don't declare `winCount` twice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert `winCount` to a string when creating the label:

```
int winCount = 0;
winCounter = new Label(Integer.toString(winCount));
```

To convert back to an integer from the label's value:

```
winCount = Integer.parseInt(winCounter.getText());
```

Comment: Would it also work to just go winCount = new Label("Wins: " + winCount); ?

Comment: Yes, the integer would be coerced into a String.